# What are the chances to generate a v4 UUID with all numbers?

Tags: uuid

When generating a v4 UUID, what are the chances that the UUID is all numbers and contains no letters? I've only seen a handful of these in the wild and so was wondering.

Comment: There is structure in a UUID that will impact the likelihood; for example, the 17th octet can only be numeric in a variant 0 or 1 UUID: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Universally_unique_identifier#Variants. But this isn't really a practical problem.

Answer (score 2):

I'll assume it's a variant 1 UUID, since a variant 2 UUID will never be all-numbers (the 17th hex-digit can only be `c` or `d`).

For variant 1, version 4, the 13th hex-digit will always be `4` (which is good), the 17th will be `8`, `9`, `a`, or `b` with equal probability (1/2 chance of being numeric), and the remaining 30 hex-digits are completely random, which gives each one a 10/16, or 5/8 chance of being numeric.

Since we need everything to be numeric, the probabilities simply multiply: 1/2 * (5/8)^30. And to get "1 in N" odds we can invert that fraction: 2 * (8/5)^30 ≅ 2,658,456. So not astronomically rare, but rarer than one in a million.